# /testfor command to count players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I make a `/testfor` command emit a signal when there is only one player in the required area? I understand `/testfor @a[x=,y=,z=,r=]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and easy way is to check the `SuccessCount` value of the command block using `/testforblock`:

[image: Repeating > Chain > Conditional Chain]

1. Run the `/testfor` command. The `c` parameter is set to 2 to prevent unnecessary processing, as `/testfor` is processed equal to the number of targets obtained. We only need to know if there's 1 or "more".

   ```
   /testfor @a[x=10,y=64,z=10,r=3,c=2]
   ```
2. Run a `/testforblock` command that is targeting command block #1 and looking for a `SuccessCount` of 1.

   ```
   /testforblock X Y Z minecraft:repeating_command_block -1 {SuccessCount:1}
   ```
3. **Conditional**. Command to run if there was only one player in the area.

   ```
   /say Only 1 player in area.
   ```

Checking for a `SuccessCount` of 2 means there were more than 1 player, while a value of 0 means there were no players at all.